# Graph $y=x^3-3x^2+3x-9$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Graph $y=x^3-3x^2+3x-9$

I have to use Pen and Paper.

I know how to graph a cubic equation when it has $3$ real roots .

$y=x^3-3x^2+3x-9\\~\\
y=(x-3)(x^2+3)\\~\\$

but the given equation has one real root and two imaginary roots.

Now I am confused about those imaginary roots and the turning points and don't know how to graph the equation.

I would also like to know if there are some video lectures about graphing cubic functions available online or any math site helpful for that.

I look for a short and simple way .

I have studied maths up to $12th$ grade.

[image]

Comment: I think it is equivalent to, $y=(x-1)^3-8$ $\implies$ $(y+8)=(x-1)^3$ , compare this graph with $y=x^3$. You will find a property namely -> translation of coordinate axis.

Comment: That looks like new cool method that i am not aware of.

Comment: @mann: can every cubic equation be written like that as u did.

Comment: @RK No. For example neither $y^2 = x^3$ nor $y = x (x - 1) (x - 2)$ can have that form. More precisely, only equations which can be obtained from $y = x^3$ by translation can have that form.

Comment: @RK ,if you still do not get the exact idea, take a look at this interactive graph, 
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3iujvno4wa
Here, vary the constant's $(h,k,a)$, and see cool visuals. You'd understand how it works.